# c++ error:no suitable conversion function from "math::Vec3<float>" to "float" exists

Tags: c++, object, types

- I get error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'math::Vec3' to 'float' but i don't understand why. I think **buffer is Vec3 type** and **v object is type Vec3** also.
- The **Vec3 class** is used as a generic three-dimensional vector and thus it defines several numerical operators that can be used on Vec3 and S data.

**Image.h**

```
#ifndef _IMAGE
#define _IMAGE

#include "Array.h"
#include "Serializable.h"
#include "Vec3.h"

using namespace math;

 class Image : public Array<Vec3<float>>, public Serializable

 {
 public:
    enum channel_t { RED = 0, GREEN, BLUE };          
 protected:
     Vec3<float> *buffer;    
 public:
     Vec3<float> getPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const;
  /*code*/
};

#endif
```

**Image.cpp**

```
#include "Image.h"
using namespace math;

 Vec3<float> Image::getPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const  {
 math::Vec3<float> v;
 int s = 0;

 if ((x <= Image::getWidth()) && (y <= Image::getHeight()) && (x >= 0) && (y >= 0))
 {

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i == getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 1; i == getHeight(); j++)
        {
            if (i == x - 1 && j == y - 1)
                goto label;
            else
                s = s + 3;
        }
    }
 label:
    v[Image::RED] = buffer[s + RED];       <-------------------HERE 
    v[Image::GREEN] = buffer[s + GREEN];   <-------------------I GET AN
    v[Image::BLUE] = buffer[s + BLUE];     <-------------------ERROR
 }
 return v;
 }//end of getPixel
```

**Vec3.h**

```
#ifndef _Vec3_ 
#define _Vec3_

namespace math

{

template <typename S>
 class Vec3
 {
 public:
    // data members

    //! The first coordinate of the vector
    union { S x, r; }; 

    //! The second coordinate of the vector
    union { S y, g; }; 

    //! The third coordinate of the vector
    union { S z, b; }; 

    S & operator [] (size_t index)
    {
        return *((S*)this + index);
    }

    Vec3<S> operator + (const Vec3<S> & right)
    {
        Vec3<S> left;
        left.x = x + right.x;
        left.y = y + right.y;
        left.z = z + right.z;
        return left;
    }

    Vec3<S> operator - (const Vec3<S> & right)
    {
        Vec3<S> left;
        left.x = x - right.x;
        left.y = y - right.y;
        left.z = z - right.z;
        return left;
    }

    Vec3<S> operator * (const Vec3<S> & right)
    {
        Vec3<S> left;
        left.x = x * right.x;
        left.y = y * right.y;
        left.z = z * right.z;
        return left;
    }

    Vec3<S> operator * (S right)
    {
        Vec3<S> left;
        left.x = x * right;
        left.y = y * right;
        left.z = z * right;
        return left;
    }

    Vec3<S> operator / (S right)
    {
        Vec3<S> left;
        left.x = x / right;
        left.y = y / right;
        left.z = z / right;
        return left;
    }

    Vec3<S> operator / (const Vec3<S> & right)
    {
        Vec3<S> left;
        left.x = x / right.x;
        left.y = y / right.y;
        left.z = z / right.z;
        return left;
    }

    Vec3<S> & operator += (const Vec3<S> & right)
    {
        x += right.x;
        y += right.y;
        z += right.z;
        return *this;
    }

    Vec3<S> & operator -= (const Vec3<S> & right)
    {
        x -= right.x;
        y -= right.y;
        z -= right.z;
        return *this;
    }

    Vec3<S> & operator /= (const Vec3<S> & right)
    {
        x /= right.x;
        y /= right.y;
        z /= right.z;
        return *this;
    }

    Vec3<S> & operator *= (const Vec3<S> & right)
    {
        x *= right.x;
        y *= right.y;
        z *= right.z;
        return *this;
    }

    Vec3<S> & operator *= (S right)
    {
        x *= right;
        y *= right;
        z *= right;
        return *this;
    }

    Vec3<S> & operator /= (S right)
    {
        x /= right;
        y /= right;
        z /= right;
        return *this;
    }

    Vec3<S>(S x, S y, S z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    Vec3<S>(S val) : x(val), y(val), z(val) {}

    Vec3<S>() : x(), y(), z() {}

    Vec3<S>(const Vec3<S> & right) : x(right.x), y(right.y), z(right.z) {}

    Vec3<S> & operator = (const Vec3<S> & right)
    {
        x = right.x;
        y = right.y;
        z = right.z;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator == (const Vec3<S> & right) const
    {
        return x == right.x && y == right.y && z == right.z;
    }

    bool operator != (const Vec3<S> & right) const
    {
        return x != right.x || y != right.y || z != right.z;
    }
  };

  template<typename S>
  Vec3<S> operator * (S a, Vec3<S> v)
  {
    return v*a;
  }


  template<typename S>
  Vec3<S> operator * (int a, Vec3<S> v)
  {
    return v*S(a);
  }

  template<typename S>
  Vec3<S> operator * (Vec3<S> v, int a)
  {
    return v*S(a);
  }

  template<typename S>
  Vec3<S> operator / (Vec3<S> v, int a)
  {
    return v/S(a);
  }
} // namespace math

#endif
```

Comment: FWIW this is definitely a case of "prefer aggregation over inheritence". There's no reason an `Image` should derive from `Array`, rather it should have an `Array` as a member.

Comment: Why is your `buffer` a pointer, rather than an instance? _I think buffer is Vec3 type_, why would you think that? it's of type _pointer to Vec3_, and, because of that, `buffer[s + RED]` statement produces an instance of type `Vec3<float>`, which, sure enough, can't be converted to a simple float.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_IMAGE`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

v and buffer have different types:

```
Vec3<float> *buffer;    
math::Vec3<float> v;
```

buffer is pointer to Vec3 and when you write "buffer[s + RED];" you try to get s + RED element of pointer. But in v vector and v[Image::RED] is red channel (it is float).

Try to use this:

```
v[Image::RED] = buffer[s][RED];
```

Comment: How do you know, that `buffer` is allocated as an array? If it isn't - you are suggesting something that may lead to an UB.

Comment: @Unick this is correct, but i dont think i get the same think!
i want to copy buffer's element in Vec3 vector! Maybe i have to edit and upload the Vec3.h file

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` is not of `math::Vec3` type but a pointer to object of such type, which can be also interpreted as an array of such objects. `buffer[s + RED]` is one element of this array, so it's of `math::Vec3` type while `v[Image::RED]` is of `float` type.

You may want to write

```
v[Image::RED] = buffer[s][Image::RED];
```

Comment: How do you know, that `buffer` is allocated as an array? If it isn't - you are suggesting something that may lead to an UB.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: I didn't write it is allocated as an array. Maybe it is, maybe it isn't, we don't know. I wrote it "can be interpreted as an array" which is true in my opinion (and that's exactly what author is doing).

Comment: `buffer[s][Image::RED]` suggests UB if `buffer` wasn't allocated as an array. It **isn't** exactly what the author is doing. Author may have wanted to access `s + Image::RED`th element of underlying `Vec<float>` as well. Without clarification it's impossible to tell, and answers shouldn't contain any speculation.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Author **is** treating `buffer` as an array. Probably intentionally (`s` seems to be some magically computed index), but maybe not. We don't know. That's why I wrote "you **may** want to write". Question wasn't "how to do what I want to do" but "why I'm getting an error". My answer answers the question and suggests **possible** correct solution of the main problem. Of course, it doesn't solve all issues that may be present in the code.

Comment: @pepper0 He may treat it as an array, but you can't, possibly know, that `buffer` was allocated as an array. `Vec3` has overloaded `operator[]`, he may have wanted to call that. If the question lacks the information for correct answer - you should ask for clarification, rather than providing a random guess, that may work in one case, and may not in others.

Answer (score 0):

`v` is of type `math::Vec3<float>` and `v[0]` is a `float`.
`buffer` is a pointer to `Vec3<float>` and by indexing it you use `operator[]` of the pointer, which is array access. So by `buffer[i]` you get a `Vec3<float>`, which is not convertible to a simple `float`.

Comment: *sigh* How do you know if `buffer` was allocated as an array? If it wasn't - you are suggesting UB. Answers shouldn't contain any speculation.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: You are right, we cannot know the state of `buffer`, i removed the line. I assumed it was allocated because of the access in Image.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` is a *pointer* to `Vec3<float>`, so `buffer[k]` is a `Vec3<float>`.
And `v[x]` is a `float`, not a `Vec3<float>`.

Your indexing suggests that you intend to have `buffer` be a "flat" representation of pixels as `float`s, in which case you could use

```
std::vector<float> buffer;
```

(or `char* buffer;` but that invites a whole mess of memory management problems.)

and you can use arithmetic rather than a search loop:

```
Vec3<float> Image::getPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const  {
    math::Vec3<float> v;
    if (x < getWidth() && y < getHeight() && x >= 0 && y >= 0)
    {
        int s = 3 * y * getWidth() + 3 * x;
        v[RED] = buffer[s + RED];
        v[GREEN] = buffer[s + GREEN];
        v[BLUE] = buffer[s + BLUE];
    }
    return v;
}
```

(This uses zero-based indexing; your code seems conflicted about whether pixels are zero-based or one-based.)